# Add a new line character after a "{" or ";" or "}" in java while using string builder

Tags: java, regex, string, stringbuilder

While using the stringbuilder class i need to append the "\n" after every "{" or "}" or ";".And then need to write the same in file.

Output of stringbuilder object i.e

```
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

is

```
nav {  ul {    list-style: none;    margin: 0;    padding: 0;  }  li { display: inline-block; }  a {        display: block;    padding: 6px 12px;    text-decoration: none;  }
```

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Use a positive lookbehind like below.

```
string.replaceAll("(?<=[{;}])", "\n");
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=[{;}])` Positive lookbehind asserts that the match must be preceded by `{` or `}` or `;` symbols.
- If there is no token given after the look-behind, then it matches the boundary. In our case, it would match all the boundaries which exists just after to `{` or `}` or `;` symbols.
- Replacing all the matched boundaries with `\n` newline character will give you the desired output.

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
System.out.println( sb.toString().replaceAll("([{};])", "$1\n") );
```

This regex matches any of `{` OR `}` or `;` using character class: `[{};]` and captures it into `$1` (back reference). In the replacement we just `$1` followed by `\n` (newline) to inset a newline after those characters.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you iterate the character of your `String` and add a newline after any of your candidate characters `{};` like

```
String str = "nav {  ul {    list-style: none;    "
    + "margin: 0;    padding: 0;  }  li { "
    + "display: inline-block; }  a { display: block;"
    +"    padding: 6px 12px;    text-decoration: none;  }";
for (char ch : str.toCharArray()) {
    System.out.printf("%c", ch);
    if (ch == '{' || ch == '}' || ch == ';') {
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Output is (as requested)

```
nav {
  ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  li {
 display: inline-block;
 }
  a {
 display: block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
```

Comment: I like this approach. Avoids the regex overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Just Create a Condition :

try this.

```
        char [] arraySb = sb.toCharArray();
        String result = "";

        for(char singleLetter : arraySb){
            if(singleLetter == '{' || singleLetter == '}' || singleLetter == ';'){
                result += (singleLetter + "\n");
            }else{
                result += singleLetter;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below Java Code:

```
String line = "nav {  ul {    list-style: none;    margin: 0;    padding: 0;  }  li { display: inline-block; }  a {        display: block;    padding: 6px 12px;    text-decoration: none;  }";
System.out.println(line.replaceAll("(?<=(\\{|\\}|;))", "\n"));
```